# How do I detect if user has set banner style alerts or 'normal' style alerts for local notifications in my app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I simply want to detect if a user has set alert style notifications to 'banners', rather than 'alerts'.

I'm able to pull up

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().types
```

to detect if user has set .None, .Badge, .Sound, or .Alert... but there's no 'Banner' type. So, is there some other way I can check this? Thanks.

EDIT: Will not be submitting this app to AppStore.

Comment: I wonder why do you need this info?

Comment: @Bhumit. To check if I am properly spamming the user if their device is not compliant with current settings. (iDevices will not be owned by user)

Comment: You have to think of another way to do that feature. I don't think this is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Banners are just a way that alerts can be presented. Alerts are either presented as banners, alerts or not at all depending on how the user has configured their device. In addition, a user can choose whether they should be shown in Notification Center, on the lock screen, on Apple Watch or other devices with Bluetooth LE with [ANCS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html). All of this is up to the user and the alert should be delivered in the same way regardless.

Why is it interesting for you to figure out how the user has configured all these things?